rotate image on digital crown apple watch and different images appear after tap on screen. different angle rotation will shown different images
I am able to rotate image according digital crown but after tap on screen only 1 image appear. I want to it to image at like fortune wheel and shown different image appear after tap on screen. Different angle of the wheel will shown different image appear after tap on next page
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scrollAmount = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: QuakeView()) {    
                   ZStack {
                    Image("Q")
                        .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 206.0, height: 206.0)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)             .rotationEffect(.degrees(scrollAmount * -51.43))
                    
                    ZStack {
                        Image("IMG")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)           .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100.0)
                    .accessibilityIdentifier("Identifier")        }
                .offset(x: 0)
                .focusable(true)
                .digitalCrownRotation($scrollAmount, from: 0, through: 14, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

